# My rails form is not working with has_scope

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms

(I have been coding for barely a month so apologies if it's a stupid question). I have a user model just with name, email and type. I have created an index form that you can filter by type and it should show the results.
Form and filters show as expected by I have 2 problems:
1. The usertype is duplicated. For example, if I have 5 users (created with the faker gem) each one of them is customer or supplier, the filter shows customer and supplier 5 times instead of twice
2. When I select a filter, it all results are shown and they are not filtered.

This is my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :microposts
scope :by_userType, ->  userType { where(:userType => userType) }
```

This is my Controller

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  has_scope :by_userType, type: :array #, :using => [:userType]


  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  #def index
  #  @users = User.all
  #end

  def index
    @users = apply_scopes(User).all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: 'User was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :userType)
    end
end
```

This is my form:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Users</h1>


<%= form_tag users_path, method: 'get', id: "users_search" do%>
<% @users = User.all %>
<% @users.each do |user|%>
<%= check_box_tag "by_userType[]", user.userType %><%= user.userType %><br>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag "submit" %>
<% end %>

<div id="users"><%= render 'user_list' %></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
      $.get($('#users_search').attr('action'),
      $('#users_search').serialize(), null, 'script');
      return false;
    });

  $('users_search').submit(function() {
    $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, 'script');
    return false;
    });
  });

</script>
```

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Could you show us more of your views? user_list partial for example?

Answer (score 0):

So a couple of things here.  First of all, welcome to rails, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

+1 for asking a question and providing code examples for what you've done so far.

Please note that for standardization, case is important in rails.  For declaration of scopes you should use snake case.  UserModel is the class name, user_model would be snake case.

Now as far as the actual implementation, I would do it somewhat differently.  If you notice most of the ajax-filtering of one model based on a field doesn't use the same model as the parameter, it's not hte ONLY way, but I prefer it, as it allows flexibility for adding extra fields to user_type later.  Meaning, if you extract user type into it's own model, then you can easily filter your users from the user_type attribute of `:name`.

So your user model would have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts
  belongs_to :user_type
  scope :by_user_type, ->  user_type { where(:user_type => user_type) }
end
```

Then create a new model called user_model

```
rails g scaffold user_model name:string slug:string avatar:string
```

** Note that the additional fields are just examples, name is hte only necessary one.  But if you want to let users do url searches, the slug is easy to use. i.e.  yoursite.com/user_type/sellers

Now create a migration to remove your existing userType field in users and a new one for the relationship.

```
rails g migration modify_user_type_in_user
```

And the contents of that file would be

```
class ModifyUserTypeInUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :users, :userType
    add_reference :users, :user_type, index: true
  end
end
```

Now edit the new `user_type.rb` model and add the relationship for `users`

```
class UserType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users 
end
```

You also need to use UJS, which you didn't mention in your post.  When your form field is clicked on, it's sending a javascript (ajax) request.  This means that in order to change the data, you'll need a javascript response template.

So add the file `app/views/users/index.js.erb` and put inside it these contents:

```
$("#users").html('<%= j(render("user_list", users: @users)) %>');
$("table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even)").css("background","#BD9FB1");
```

Lastly, you'll need to change your form, so it represents the correct searchable model.  So edit 'app/views/users/index.html.erb'

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>User Filter</h1>

<%= form_tag users_path, method: 'get', id: "users_search" do%>
<% @user_types = UserType.all %>
<% @user_types.each do |user_type|%>
<%= check_box_tag "by_user_type[]", user_type.id %><%= user_type.name %><br>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag "submit" %>
<% end %>

<div id="users"><%= render 'user_list' %></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
      $.get($('#users_search').attr('action'),
      $('#users_search').serialize(), null, 'script');
      return false;
    });

  $('users_search').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, 'script');
    return false;
    });
  });

</script>
```